# Can’t send over a SSH key to Windows 11 but process works with Windows 10. Why?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-11, scp

I'm running some tests with SSH with public keys. I am generating the keys with the `ssh-keygen` command in my Linux machine.

I'd like to use the  SCP command to copy the public key to my Windows 11 system with this command

```sh
scp id_rsa.pub win11usr@192.168.33.80:%programdata%/ssh
```

When this command runs on my Linux machine it works successfully but on the Windows 11 machine I can't see the file I copied over.

I tried again with Windows 10 and it worked and I can see the file in the directory. I wonder why I don't get the same results in Windows 11?

Comment: Put the full path instead of using a variable.

Comment: Yup. I tried that and still nothing.